# UPDATING TO KERNEL 4.15

Tags: updates, kernel

I have not enough experience to know if the following steps I think I have to do to update the kernel of my Elementary upto 4.15 are correct. Can somebody check it and tell me and tell me if it will work 100%:
1.- Create a directory specifictally to do this operation. For example /inux415
2. - cd /linux415
3.- Download as follow (for 64 bits of course:
-http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily/2018-01-29/linux-headers- 4.15.0-999_4.15.0-999.201801282100_all.deb
- http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily/2018-01-29/linux-headers-4.15.0-999-generic_4.15.0-999.201801282100_amd64.deb
- http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily/2018-01-29/linux-image-4.15.0-999-generic_4.15.0-999.201801282100_amd64.deb
4- Install all: sudo dpkg - i *.deb
5.- Reboot.

I hope that somebody will help me.

Thanks and blessings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using Ukuu:
http://www.teejeetech.in/p/ukuu-kernel-upgrade-utility.html